# How to redirect_to a certain anchor on the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a cart/line item function but every time I add an item to the cart the page refreshes to the to the top again.

My anchor looks like this

```
<div id="<%= product.id %>">
```

This works, it brings me to product.id=4

```
 def create
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @line_item = @cart.add_product(product)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to(request.env['HTTP_REFERER'] += '#4' )}
        format.js { @current_item = @line_item }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

but this does not work

```
    format.html { redirect_to(request.env['HTTP_REFERER'] += '#{@product.id}' )}
```

It instead creates ...:3000/#{@product.id}

Comment: Have you tried like this `redirect_to "#{request.env['HTTP_REFERER']}##{@product.id}"` ?

Answer (score 1):

[String interpolation works only on double-quote-delimited strings](http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/bonus/string_interpolation.html).

> That means that:
>
> ```rb
> puts "Interpolation works in double quoted strings: #{1 + 2}."
> puts 'And it does not work in single quoted strings: #{1 + 2}.'
> ```
>
> will print out:
>
> ```rb
> Interpolation works in double quoted strings: 3.
> And it does not work in single quoted strings: #{1 + 2}.
> ```

So, change `'#{@product.id}'` to `"#{@product.id}"`.

Also, the `+=` doesn't make a lot of sense there. Why are you mutating the referrer? You should use plain `+` instead.